# Maximal analytic continuation

Tags: complex-manifolds, analytic-continuation

I'm currently reading about the concept of a “maximal analytic continuation” from Forster's book *Lectures on Riemann Surfaces* (see Section 7). There are a bunch of definitions to unpack before I can ask my question, so I'll start with those.

---

#### Definitions

Let $\mathcal{O}$ be the sheaf of [germs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germ_(mathematics)) of holomorphic functions over a Riemann surface $X$. Given a germ $\varphi \in \mathcal{O}_x$ ($\mathcal{O}_x$ denotes the stalk of $\mathcal{O}$ over the point $x \in X$), we define an *analytic continuation* of $\varphi$ as a quadruplet $(Y, p, f, y)$ satisfying:

1. $Y$ is a Riemann surface, and $p : Y \to X$ is an unbranched holomorphic map (and thus a local diffeomorphism).
2. $f : Y \to \mathbb{C}$ is a holomorphic map on $Y$.
3. $p(y) = x$.
4. $[f \circ (p|_{U_y})^{-1}]_x = \varphi$, where $U_y$ is a small neighborhood about $y$ such that the restriction $p|_{U_y}$ is a diffeomorphism.

Here's an example of an analytic continuation to provide some intuition. Suppose $X = \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$, and suppose $\varphi$ is a germ associated to the complex logarithm at a point $x \in X$. Let $Y$ be the “graph”
$$
Y := \{(z, w) : z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}, \exp(w) = z\}.
$$
($Y$ is just the set of ordered pairs $(z, \log z)$ over all branches of the logarithm.) Let $p : (z, w) \mapsto z$ and $f : (z, w) \mapsto w$ be the associated projection maps. Setting $y$ to be the value of the germ $\varphi$ at $x$, one can show that $(Y, p, f, y)$ is an analytic continuation of $\varphi$. Viewing $Y$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and projecting it onto its first, second, and fourth coordinates, we see that $Y$ is isomorphic to a helicoid: the Riemann surface that the complex logarithm has classically been defined over.

Forster further defines the notion of the *maximal analytic continuation* of a germ, which he makes rigorous by defining via a universal property. We can always construct the maximal analytic continuation of a germ $\varphi$ as follows. We define the [étalé space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)#The_%C3%A9tal%C3%A9_space_of_a_sheaf) $E(\mathcal{O})$ associated to $\mathcal{O}$ as the disjoint union of all stalks of $\mathcal{O}$ (i.e., the set of all germs). The étalé space is a Hausdorff topological space, and has the structure of a Riemann surface via the projection map $\pi : [g]_x \mapsto x$. Let $Y$ be the connected component of the étalé space $E(\mathcal{O})$ that contains the germ $\varphi$. Setting $f([g]_x) := g(x)$, one can show that $(Y, \pi, f, \varphi)$ is the maximal analytic continuation of $\varphi$.

---

#### Question

My issue is that this definition does not seem to be the “correct” definition of analytic continuation. In particular, the maximal analytic continuation of a germ $\varphi$ depends on the choice of the space $X$. This is easily seen from Forster's construction of a maximal analytic continuation. If $\varphi$ is a germ about a point $x \in X$, we can repeat the construction of the maximal analytic continuation with the space $X$ replaced by another space $X' \subseteq X$ that contains the point $x$. However, the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{X'}$ associated to $X'$ may not be the same as the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ associated to $X$, so this may yield two different maximal analytic continuations! Meanwhile, the germ $\varphi$ is a local property, so it seems nonsensical for its analytic continuation to depend on the space $X$ it lives in.

Is there some purpose to Forster's definition that I'm not understanding? Perhaps, is there some alternative notion of a “maximal analytic continuation” that is independent of the choice of $X$?

Comment: Why do you expect uniqueness? I guess that any definition of "analytic continuation" of a germ of holomorphic function at $x$ will be given up to local biholomorphisms around $x$. And any unbranched holomorphic map $Y \to X$ is a local biholomorphism (by the Inverse Function Theorem).

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Yeah, it makes sense why analytic continuations are defined up to local biholomorphisms. My issue is that the definition of what an analytic continuations is (and what ends up being the maximal analytic continuation) is dependent on the space $X$. It seems that swapping $X$ for another surface may yield a different set of analytic continuations (in a non-isomorphic sense).